# Lie Algebra SU(2)

Tags: hilbert-spaces, lie-groups, lie-algebras, spin-geometry, groups-of-lie-type

Given a two dimensional Hilbert-space, $\mathcal{H}$, and a vector $\eta \in \mathcal{H}$, of this space,

if $\eta$ transforms in SU(2) like this,

$$\eta \rightarrow e^{(-i\alpha \vec{\sigma}\vec{n}/2)}\cdot \eta$$

$\textbf{Find }$ how does this quantity
$${\eta}^{T} i \sigma_{2} \eta$$

$\textbf{transform in SU(2)}.$

(Where $\sigma_{k}$ are Pauli Matrices, $\vec{n}\cdot\vec{n}=1$, $i \in \mathbb{C}$ is the imaginary unit, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\eta^{T}$ is the transpose of the vector $\eta$).

HELP: $i\sigma_{2}\sigma_{i}=-i\sigma^{*}i\sigma_{2}$

Comment: By $\eta^T$, do you mean the covariant form of $\eta$ ?

Comment: How are the Pauli-matrices to act on the Hilbert space if you have not chosen a special basis?

Comment: @vnd I don't have more information. I suppose that's the transpose of the two-dimensional vector $\eta$. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @s.harp this is the information that i have. Sorry. (I suppose is the standard basis). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: This is an exercise out of a book? Can you tell us what book it is, at least?

Comment: In the standard basis $\sigma_z$ is diagonal, and $i\sigma_y= \left[\begin{array}{l}0&1\\-1&0\end{array}\right]$. For the state $\eta = \left[\begin{array}{l}a\\b\end{array}\right]$, $\eta^Ti\sigma_y\eta$ evaluates to 0.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez is en exam-exercise. Es el ejercicio de un examen de 3° Física UAB, Métodos Matemáticos Avanzados.

Comment: @vnd can you prove it using the relation given at the top of the question? $$\eta \rightarrow e^{(-i\alpha \vec{\sigma}\vec{n}/2)}\cdot \eta$$ thank you

Comment: @Sergi $e^{(-i\alpha \vec{\sigma}\vec{n}/2)}$ is the unitary operator of rotation by $-\alpha$ about $\boldsymbol{n}$. Such an operator should transform 0 to 0.

Comment: @vnd of course. But what I think the corrector may want is that, first, using $$\eta \rightarrow e^{(-i\alpha \vec{\sigma}\vec{n}/2)}\cdot \eta$$, transform $\eta^{T}$, then $i\sigma_{2}$ and finally $\eta$ finding this result (0). But I don't know how to do it exactly.